# How to sync the changs from the remote repo to the workspace?

Tags: git

**Scenario ->**

1. I am working on a branch different from master lets called it `Different`.
2. As I have created a pull request to review `Different` branch to all the team members.
3. One of the members checked in certain piece of code in the pull request and checked in the changes.

**Question 1:** What should I do here in order so that the changes made in the particular code should reflect with my workspace and local repo.

4. Lets suppose I forgot to do Question 1 and made some changes in my workspace according to the reviews of the other team members and changed many files as per the reviews.
5. Now when after committing those changes in the local repo I realized that I need to change the file which is changed by one of the reviewer, If I push this without doing the process then It will be unable to push to the remote repo, and major conflicts will occur.

**Question:2** How will I deal with point 5 without merging?

Answer (score 0):

In general I think you don't need to worry about a branch with a pending pull request behaving any differently than any other branch.  As you can see, it is still possible to pull and push from the `Different` branch.

Off the top of my head, if you need to bring in remote changes (i.e. commits) *without* making a merge commit, you could try rebasing the `Different` branch on the remote counterpart, i.e.

```
git fetch origin
git checkout Different
git rebase origin/Different
```

With this approach, you would be laying your commit/fix on top of the current remote branch (which presumably also has a fix commit of its own).  You can now push `Different` to keep the pull request up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Q1 : To get modification locally, you can simply do `git pull` (which is the same as doing `git fetch` and `git merge`)

Q2 : If you commited something locally without fetching remote changes first the idea is the same but you need to do a `rebase` instead of `merge` with `git pull --rebase` (which will do a `git fetch` and then a `git rebase`)

Actually in the second case, you could also do a merge but it will result in a merge commit (of the remote branch into your local branch) which is not wrong but tends to make the history more difficult to read and understand.